# was not hit the stumps vs. did not hit the stumps

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, auxiliary-verbs

Please explain the difference between *was not and did not* in my below example.

No, ball *was not* hit the stumps.

Or

No, ball *did not* hit the stumps.

Answer (score 1):

Your first example, as is, is ungrammatical:

> No, ball was not hit the stumps.

The verb **was** shows that the ball underwent (or not, because of the negation in your case) the action of someone or something. To make it grammatical the action verb **hit** should be followed by the preposition **by**:

> No, the ball was not hit by his foot.
>
> No, the ball was not hit by the bat.

Your second example is also ungrammatical because it lacks the definite article **the**.

> No, ball did not hit the stumps.

To make it grammatical we should add the definite article **the**:

> No, the ball did not hit the stumps.

So the second example shows the ball as the doer of the action.

Answer (score 0):

No, the ball didn't hit the stumps.

The sentence is in the active voice and grammatically correct.

If you change it into the passive voice, the sentence will be:

No, the stumps were not hit by the ball.

The sentence "No, the ball was not hit the stumps is incorrect grammatically; it's neither in the active voice nor in the passive voice.